# How to resolve ValueError Length mismatch Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 7 elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently stuck on this error for a while.

The lond dataframe has 6807 rows by 15 columns. Column names are Neighbourhood, Neighbourhood Listings, Mean price, PostCode,   Borough,    Neighbourhood Postcode, Latitude,   Longitude,  Nearest Train Station, Distance to Station, London Zone, Property Type, Room Type, Price,   Location Review Scores.

What I am trying to achieve is to use the function to do the following.

1. Extracting each neighbourhood's geographical coordinates.
2. Extracting the top 100 venues (including category type) within a 200m radius for each neighbourhood.
3. Clean the json data and convert the data into a pandas dataframe.

Please help me. This is my first project of this magnitude.

```py
    #Defining the to get nearby venues
    def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=100):

        venues_list=[]
        for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
            print(name)

            # Creating the API request URL
            url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll= 
            {},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
                CLIENT_ID, 
                CLIENT_SECRET, 
                VERSION, 
                lat, 
                lng, 
                radius, 
                LIMIT)

            # Making the GET request to extract json data
            #results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
            results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]#['groups'][0]['items']
            # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
            venues_list.append([(
                name, 
                lat, 
                longi, 
                v['venue']['name'], 
                v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
                v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
                v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

        nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
        nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighbourhood', 
                      'Neighbourhood Latitude', 
                      'Neighbourhood Longitude', 
                      'Venue', 
                      'Venue Latitude', 
                      'Venue Longitude', 
                      'Venue Category']

        return(nearby_venues)

    #Calling the getNearbyVenues function for each neighbourhood to create a dataframe lon_venues
    lond = lon_neighbs201.head(600)
    LIMIT = 10
    lon_venues = getNearbyVenues (names = lond['Neighbourhood'],
                                           latitudes = lond['Latitude'],
                                           longitudes = lond['Longitude']
                                          )
    lon_venues
```

Comment: I would start with checking the df: ```nearby_venues``` before the line, where you define columns for it i.e. ```nearby_venues.columns=...``` it probably doesn't have 7 columns (as per error message).

Answer (score 0):

I think, a more intuitive costruction will be:

1. Change *append* in the loop into *extend*. This way *venues_list* will be
   a list of tuples. Each inner tuple will contain data for each row and the
   outer list will be a list of "rows".
2. When you create *nearby_venues*, pass just *venues_list* as the first
   parameter (instead of the list comprehension you had so far).
3. There is no need to set column names in a separate instruction.
   Column list can be passed as *columns* parameter in the instruction
   creating the DataFrame.

So creation of *nearby_venues* should look like below:

```
nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame(venues_list, columns = ['Neighbourhood',
    'Neighbourhood Latitude', 'Neighbourhood Longitude', 'Venue',
    'Venue Latitude', 'Venue Longitude', 'Venue Category'])
```